# Importing from a large C++ library

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, parquet

1. I am trying to work with the following library: https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp. Once built, the library has a number of shared objects generated(libparquet.so,libarrow.so,libsnappy.so,etc). In such a situation to work with this library in my own single source file, I would have to use multiple -I/-L statements in a Makefile probably pointing to specific locations. Is there a shorter, simpler and more efficient way?
2. Currently when running the example provided: reader-writer.cc, I'm copying the file outside this project in a new folder renaming it to test.cpp. Then I copy the libarrow/libparquet.so files in this directory and run the command as explained here. The compiler runs successfully, but the linker fails with the following log.

> /tmp/ccBbmmG9.o: In function `main':
>   test.cpp:(.text+0xc4d): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnWriter >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, bool const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0xcb6): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnWriter<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)1> >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, int const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0xd6d): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnWriter >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, long const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0xdf7): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnWriter<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)3> >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, parquet::Int96 const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0xe74): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnWriter >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, float const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0xef1): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnWriter<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)5> >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, double const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1034): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnWriter >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, parquet::ByteArray const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1065): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnWriter<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)6> >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, parquet::ByteArray const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1153): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnWriter >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, parquet::FixedLenByteArray const*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x146f): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnReader<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)0> >::ReadBatch(long, short*, short*, bool*, long*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x15c1): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnReader >::ReadBatch(long, short*, short*, int*, long*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1702): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnReader<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)2> >::ReadBatch(long, short*, short*, long*, long*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x18c3): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnReader >::ReadBatch(long, short*, short*, parquet::Int96*, long*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1a5a): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnReader<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)4> >::ReadBatch(long, short*, short*, float*, long*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1bc3): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnReader >::ReadBatch(long, short*, short*, double*, long*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1d3f): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnReader<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)6> >::ReadBatch(long, short*, short*, parquet::ByteArray*, long*)'
>   test.cpp:(.text+0x1fe7): undefined reference to`parquet::TypedColumnReader >::ReadBatch(long, short*, short*, parquet::FixedLenByteArray*, long*)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: _"Is there a shorter, simpler and more efficient way?"_ No.

Comment: Which question is it a duplicate of?

Comment: The one linked at the very top of the page.